# La « desseralité » : réflexions ?

Tags: adjectifs, alimentation, néologismes, suffixes, euphonie

Je lis un article [*Une Française sacrée meilleure pâtissière du monde*](https://www.lapresse.ca/gourmand/201906/11/01-5229706-une-francaise-sacree-meilleure-patissiere-du-monde.php) (par une [organisation](https://www.theworlds50best.com/blog/News/jessica-prealpato-worlds-best-pastry-chef-desseralite.html)). On fait référence à un thème, la *desseralité*. Selon la source, on parle de l'union de [*naturalité*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17066134), ce « caractère naturel d'une chose, appartenance à la nature » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/naturalit%C3%A9)), un thème cher au chef [Alain Ducasse](https://youtu.be/m-Ca8JnYW4A), et de *dessert* (naturalité+dessert), ou [ailleurs](http://foodandsens.com/made-by-f-and-s/beaux-livres-de-chefs-desseralite-par-jessica-prealpato/) on dit « ce qui concerne la nature profonde du dessert », ce qui semble relever aussi directement de la suffixation [*-ité*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-it%C3%A9), « indiquant une qualité dérivée d'une base adjective » (TLFi), même si ici on aurait plutôt un substantif.

Par ailleurs le dessert reste une création, un produit transformé et c'est beaucoup aussi la nature profonde du fruit qui est mise de l'avant avec cette approche ; le respect et la connaissance intime du produit n'est certainement pas en rupture avec la gastronomie française traditionnelle puisque c'en est il me semble une de ses caractéristiques fondamentales. Afin de m'aider à explorer ces questions de « philosophie gastronomique » et à discuter de ces amalgames, j'aimerais savoir :

- S'il existe un adjectif pour le substantif *dessert* ?
- Si l'on choisirait *fruit* ou *fruitier* à suffixer avec
  *-ité/-ralité* (*naturalité*) et quel en serait le résultat ; penserait-on à suffixer *fruit/fruitier* avec [*-tion*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-tion), sur le modèle de [*naturalisation*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/naturalisation), en composition avec *dessert* ou *pâtisserie* ?
- Si l'on trouve que la qualité intrinsèque du dessert est davantage
  révélée par *desserité*, *dessertité* que par *desseralité* et pourquoi ; trouve-t-on l'union avec *naturalité* porteuse de sens et y perçoit-on spontanément en arrière-plan *naturalité* ou *vitalité*, par exemple, et cette union servirait-elle surtout à créer l'euphonie ?

Answer (score 1):

- Même après recherche, il ne me semble pas qu'il existe un adjectif relatif au substantif *"Dessert"* ni même un autre adjectif qui en exprimerait le sens.
- J'ai eu un peu de mal à comprendre la question, mais je pense que plutôt que le suffixe *-tion*, on prendrait le suffixe *-if* pour donner *fructif* qui n'est pas sans rappeler *fructifier*, donnant un sens plus explicite à l'aspect de "création", de "production". Combiné à *naturalité*, on obtiendrait, par exemple, *fructialité*.
- À mon sens le néologisme *desseralité* n'a pas plus de sens que *dessertité* ou *desserité*, car même l'aspect de *naturalité* n'est pas évident. Mon opinion serait que ce mot a pour but premier de créer l'euphonie, car il est également le titre d'un livre dédié à ce sujet, et que le titre d'un livre est l'un des critères de vente majeurs.